# How to use Python Pandas to read a csv file from a C# Process

Tags: python, c#, pandas, process, python-3.7

I am writing a Python program that needs to execute via a new process in C#. I have the Python program executing in C#, but it no longer works once I try to use Pandas. Do you have any suggestions of how I can make using Pandas work? Below are the two Python scripts: they both work when I run them in the Spyder IDE, but only the first works when I run through C# and the second does not.

This works:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
import sys

word = "test test" #sys.argv[1]

print(word)
```

This does not work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""
import sys
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("FILE/PATH/HERE", skiprows = 3)
word = "test test" #sys.argv[1]

print(word)
```

Comment: Did you install pandas?

Comment: Pandas works fine when I run the code in Spyder. Does it need to be installed somewhere else? @TarunR

Comment: What if the error message? What does it mean “does not work”?

Comment: It means the script will not run and I get no output in my C# process. The print statement never gets executed. However, everything runs smoothly with Pandas when I'm running the script in Spyder. @divingTobi

Comment: I assume it has something to to with the strange CSV file path "FILE/PATH/HERE". Assuming that this path exists relative to the Python file, when executing the Python file in a C# application, the current path is the one of the C# application. If this application is not in the same folder as the Python file, this would cause a `FileNotFoundError`, hence `print(word)` is never executed. By the way: How do you run the Python file?

Comment: That would make sense. I'm using the absolute file name "C:/File/Path/Here" - does it need to be a relative path to the C# application? I've found in the past few minutes that the problem appears to be with the ```import pandas as pd``` line. If ```print("string")``` is called above ```import pandas as pd``` then it prints, if its called after then it does not execute. Any ideas on how to resolve that? @JürgenBayer

Comment: I tried it out and importing pandas resulted in the error "Importing the numpy c-extensions failed" with the original error "DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: The specified module could not be found". This is probably solved by installing the Intel mkl-service package (conda install -c intel mkl-service) as stated in the error message, but this failed in my case.